# Error of ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

Tags: python

I don’t know how to import this utils without any problem.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

This problem occurs in both jupiter and spyder.

```
import numpy as np
from utils import load_dataset
from utils import download_stock
from networks import StockAgentDQN,StockAgentDQNshort,StockAgentDQNbold
```

Actually, I don’t know the output.

Comment: Utils is not python specific package. It might be the package of the project you are using. Post the Actual Directory Structures You are using

Comment: What @Gaurav said - in any case, the package `utils` either isn't installed or is installed somewhere that the computer won't look. I would recommend doing `pip install utils` on the command line, but the `utils` package on pypi doesn't seem like it's what you're looking for in this case - talk to your team about where they put the `utils` library you're supposed to be using

Comment: I am not good at computers and I don’t know how I can reach the Actual Directory Structures I am using. If you describe, I can post it.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I tried pip install utils, did not work.

Comment: Sure You can post

Comment: @Gaurav import os

path = os.getcwd()  
print ("The current working directory is %s" % path)
The current working directory is /Users/ozgeozler/GitHub-CS-229-RL-project

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy The output of pip install utils is                                                                        ~ ozgeozler$ pip install utils
Collecting utils
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/de/9ffaf89be661b32d1e0cff05e1af5e4fc2d608c47498975e94aca219aed4/utils-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: utils
Successfully installed utils-0.9.0

Comment: Hey i am not saying to post the code  actually for getting path, i am saying the termianl and your directory structure in UI

Comment: Anyway i found the Project, I am checking on it

Comment: Just try .utils instead of utils

Comment: I guess it also didn’t work @Gaurav

Comment: Just Do this add an `__init__.py` file to the code directory which is an empty file and after that replace `utils` with `code.utils`

Comment: This time, there occurs another problem of  “      from networks import StockAgentDQN,StockAgentDQNshort,StockAgentDQNbold

ImportError: cannot import name 'StockAgentDQN' from 'networks' (/Users/ozgeozler/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/networks/__init__.py)    "

Comment: Also Replace With other Libraries Files too like. `network` with `code.networks` and similarly in other files as well. Whatever files you see in the package you need to prefix with `code.`